# Regular expression for permutation of M characters of length N

Tags: regex, permutation

I need a regular expression that represents permutation of given M characters and the permutation string should be in length N. For example, I have 1 and 0, so `M=2` and the length of permutation string need to be 3 (ie. `N=3`), then I have:

`000, 001, 010, 011, 100, 101, 110, 111`

When `N=2`, I have:

`00, 01, 10, 11`

What should the regular expression be for this?

Thanks!

Edit:
Just want to make it clear, the input is not limited to digits, it can be letters, for example, I got `{A, T, C, G}` representing Adenine, Thymine, Cytosine and Guanine in genomics, I need to have permutation of three per group, so I can have a list like:

`ATC, ATG, ACT, AGA` etc

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried anything? This seems simple enough if you just use a character class and a quantifier.

Comment: Why do you even need a regular expression for this? Is it a requirement?

Comment: Let me know if the regex i put below is similar to what you need

Answer (score 1):

Heres a Regex to match the digits `1-n`. You can tinker with it to do what you want.

```
^(?=[1-n]{n}$)(?!.*(.).*\1).*$
```

**Sample input for n = 4**

```
1234
2431
abcde
4321
1231
3412
```

**Output**

```
1234  *MATCH*
2431  *MATCH*
abcde
9010
4321   *MATCH*
1231   *MATCH*
3412   *MATCH*
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, could you please see my latest edit?

Comment: Why on earth do you complicate so much???? `^[1234]{4}$` (or `^[1-4]{4}$` if you prefer) is perfectly adequate.

Comment: Can you be so kind to explain this regex in words?